# Saying "the what" to ask about something I don't understand

Tags: pronouns, questions

When someone says "the *something*" and i don't understand that *something* they said I say "the what" in the idea of letting them know I didn't understand what they said.

How horribly I butcher English by using that construction?

Comment: Don't worry. You're not butchering English any more than native speakers do. Since it's a question, it should be "The what?"

Comment: So you're telling me that it is correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I would say if someone said to me "Hey, did you see the frigbajazdinger over there?"

Comment: It is entirely idiomatic.

Comment: @John Whaddya mean "What?" I've got one of those.

Comment: @Nathan thank you for editing my poor post,can I know your opinion on this topic please?

Answer (score 5):

You aren't butchering English by saying "The what?" as a question. That's entirely idiomatic. In fact, if someone seems to have said a name that you didn't catch, you can also say "The who?" (or just "Who?", if the original sentence didn't have the definite article "the" beforehand).

In both cases, the idea is that you give just enough context, usually with "the", to let them know what part of the sentence you're asking about. Sometimes you need to include more. If someone says "I'm going to poke the ??? with the long pole", you might say "Poke the what?" so they know you're not asking them to repeat "the long pole".

Comment: This is all I needed to know,thank you very much and have a good day/night sir.